# Is there a way to create multiple google classroom accounts in a multi tenant application?

Tags: automation, multi-tenant, google-classroom

I am looking to create a multi-tenant apps that allows individual users to create their own google classrooms through my app. Now, when looking at the existing developer reference of google classroom api, I see only ways to manage the contents of a single classroom be it courses, students, teachers or study material. What I am looking for is a way to create multiple classroom accounts for separate users. Is this possible in any way?

Comment: What do you mean by classroom accounts in your application? The way Classroom currently works is that whenever a Google accounts create a classroom they are classified in one of the following [types of users](https://support.google.com/edu/classroom/answer/7582372) for the service.

Comment: I mean for example if someone manages a couple of educational institutions, they would need to create separate classrooms for each institutions in which they will add courses separately for each of the institution in their own classroom. In the workspace edition all I have seen so far is that a workspace admin can create classrooms for each institution manually but there is no automated way to do this yet.

Answer (score 0):

Through the API by creating a [`course`](https://developers.google.com/classroom/reference/rest/v1/courses) you are creating a classroom that can be managed by your organization, if your approach is to create classes or `courses` how it is called in the documentation, by the end user, then using the [`courses.create`](https://developers.google.com/classroom/reference/rest/v1/courses/create) should be the API needed to perform this action.

Reference:

**Method: courses.create**

**Creates a course.**

> The user specified in ownerId is the owner of the created course and added as a teacher. A non-admin requesting user can only create a course with themselves as the owner. Domain admins can create courses owned by any user within their domain.

Now, with this in mind, if you want to build an app that will serve several domains and allow them to create classes on behalf of their Teachers I would suggest checking the different [scenarios](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2) to analyze what would be the best for you.